# Launch Arcology Achievements

Tags: achievements, simcity-2013

I launched my Arcology, but I can't figure out HOW to get these achievements:

[image: Arcology Achievements]

Here is my Arcology

[image: Arcology]

---

What am I missing? I don't know how to use Arcology. For me, it is just a place at the moment, like a monument. I'm not even sure if the "benefits" are coming to my cities.

Comment: Thanks @Frank ... I'm hungry (still didn't ate and it's 18:20 (6:20pm)) ...

Comment: Maybe, I should create a question with the following "How to use the great works benefits and get they achievements" xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Launch Arcology" is different than the regular Arcology.

The Launch Arcology was available as a bonus for pre-ordering the Cities of Tomorrow expansion.

More details are [at EA's site](http://help.ea.com/en/article/simcity-cities-of-tomorrow-pre-order-information/).

Comment: Whoa, limited availability achievements? That's not cool, EA.